# Why doesn't bootstrap datatable render on mobile device

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables

I'm using [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) on my responsive website with bootstrap 4. I experience a strange behaviour when loading the page on any mobile device. The datatable is visible but it shows the information 'No data available in table'. This also happens on my laptop, but just for a brief second before the content is loaded into the table. As the table renders fine on my laptop I know that the ajax call is responding as expected, so the issue must be elsewhere. I have read forums on datatables.net and here on stackoverflow, but I cannot find a solution to this issue.  My code is posted below, and if you can point me in the right direction, please reply to this question: Why doesn't the table render on mobile device?

Ajax request with response handling:
`

```
$.ajax({
        url: '../../core/newslist/get_newslist.php', 
        data: "", 
        dataType: 'json',  
        success: function(response)
        {   
        var tableArray = response[0];

        var oTable = $("#dd_project_table").DataTable({
        "destroy": true,
        deferRender: true,
        dom: '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
        "language": {
                    "lengthMenu": "Vis _MENU_ resultater per side",
                    "zeroRecords": "Ingen prosjekter å vise",
                    "info": "",
                    "infoFiltered": "",
                    "infoEmpty": "Ingen sider å vise",
                    "sSearch": "Hurtigsøk",
                    "paginate": {
                    "previous": "Forrige",
                    "next": "Neste"}
        },

            "responsive": true,
            "searching": true,
            "scrollX": false,
            "scrollY": "700px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "autoWidth": true,
            "bSort":true,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "pageLength": 12,
            "cursor": "pointer",
            
             createdRow: function ( row, data, dataIndex, cells ) {
              $(row).attr('draggable', 'true');
            },
             drawCallback: function () {
              // Add HTML5 draggable event listeners to each row
              rows = document.querySelectorAll('#dd_project_table tbody tr');
                [].forEach.call(rows, function(row) {
                  row.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
                  row.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false)
                  row.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
                  row.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
                 row.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
                  row.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
                });
            },
            
            "aaData": tableArray
            });


});//end ajax
```

Here is the table in my html file

```
<table id="dd_project_table"  class="table table-hover table-striped display table-responsive">
<thead id="ddbox">
<tr>
  <th id="hname1" class="dd-datatable-heading" align="center"><b>#</b></th>
  <th id="hname2" class="dd-datatable-heading"><b>PROJECT</b></th>                              
  <th id="hname3" class="dd-datatable-heading"><b>LOCATION</b></th>
  <th id="hname4" class="dd-datatable-heading"><b>TYPE</b></th>
  <th id="hname6" class="dd-datatable-heading"><b>COST</b></th>
  <th id="hname8" class="dd-datatable-heading"><b>START</b></th>
  <th id="hname9" class="dd-datatable-heading"><b>END</b></th>
  <th id="hname10" class="dd-datatable-heading pull-right"><b>ACTIONS</b></th>                        
</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

I have tried different approaches by moving my code around, building the table rows dynamically ++, but no luck so far.

Comment: _As the table renders fine on my laptop I know that the ajax call is responding as expected..._ Well, no. You don't. Have you tested that hypothesis to confirm? This sounds like a data issue and not a rendering issue.

Comment: Something tells me that the issue isn't DataTable but: (1) Just because you can reach the endpoint with your computer, it doesn't mean your phone can reach it too. Check if your phone is in the same network, or if it does, it can reach your endpoint. (2) There is an error when `$.ajax` tried to reach the endpoint. So, I would add the `error: function(status, error){ /* code here */} }` and display in a textarea the error. (3) The data received by `$.ajax` isn't in the format you can use with Datatable. Maybe it has a different encode, etc. Let me know if this helped you to find the root cause.

Comment: Thank you for the input. This lead me in the direction of a regEx expression elsewhere in my code which wasnt iOS compatible. Issue is resolved.